# How to write data to existing table in Unity catalog using DLT

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

Is it possible to write data to existing table in UC using DLT pipeline? If yes, how can it be done?

@dlt.table creates a new table, but the requirement is to read data from file or other table and write to existing table UC.

Comment: having you tried any approach? If yes provide the code and errors.

Comment: I've created a table in UC and then tried writing to it from DLT pipeline but get error that the table already exists. DLT tries to create the same table at runtime but is it possible to just write to an already existing table?

Answer (score 0):

In DLT, you can create and update tables using the code below:

```py
import dlt

@dlt.table()
def csv_target():
  return spark.readStream.format("csv").load("path/to/sourceDir")

@dlt.append_flow(target = "csv_target")
def backfill():
  return spark.readStream.format("csv").load("path/to/backfill/data/dir")
```

Here, `csv_target` is created, and `@dlt.append_flow(target = "csv_target")` is used for appending.

However, this is not possible for an already existing table. If your requirement is as follows:

> The requirement is to read data from a file or another table and write to an existing table UC.

You can follow the **upsert** method in Python.

In this documentation, it mentions `DeltaTable.forPath`. Instead, you can use `DeltaTable.forName(spark, "samp_tbl.user")`.

So, if you are restricted to using DLT itself, you need to create a new streaming table initially in the DLT pipeline, which does the incremental loading.